# Azure Data Factory Deployment pipeline using ARM template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template, azure-deployment

We are trying to Deploy Azure Datafactory using Azure Group Deployment task in Azure Pipelines. The templates have been pushed into the artifacts and we are reading the Arm Templates and its Parameter files from that location

[image]

When I click Override parameters, it shows the below error:

[image]

I have checked both the json files and verified the schema format and other solution seen in google search. Still I am getting this error.

Comment: Can you post the error text? I can't see your links (blocked by my work firewall). It sounds like you aren't using YAML though..... you should really be using YAML

Comment: We are currently using classic pipeline in our organization. The error while trying to add "Override Parameters" is Template path doesnt point to a valid JSON file. Although the correct files have been added from Release pipeline's artifacts

Comment: I believe this is an issue with the classic experience. The override box is plain text box so you should be able to manually input the override. If you are looking for YAML Buid/Deployment pipelines I do have those templated for others to use. [adf_build_stage.yml](https://github.com/JFolberth/TheYAMLPipelineOne/blob/main/stages/adf_build_stage.yml) and [adf_deploy_stage.yml](https://github.com/JFolberth/TheYAMLPipelineOne/blob/main/stages/adf_deploy_stage.yml) This will support override parameters.

Comment: Thanks @DreadedFrost, We are yet to establish yaml pipelines in our organization. Currently they are setting up the CD pipeline in Releases. And stil I am struggling to rectify this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to deploy Arm template to Deploy ADF with classic pipeline instead of using AzureDeployment:CreateorUpdateResource ***I directly used  ARM Template deployment task and it read the JSON deployment file correctly***, Refer below:-

**Task:-** ARM Template Deployment:-

Add the ARM json file by visiting the correct repository and folder:-

[image]

ARM file added as a Template:-

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]